# Bootstrap 3: (Mobile) Navigation Bar auto close once you click the dropdown

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

Hi I need your expertise because its working perfectly in desktop mode but if its mobile mode its not working properly once you click the dropdown menu it will automatic close the whole navigation bar,

```
<li class="dropdown">
                            <a data-toggle="dropdown" > Shop </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/shop">All Inventory</a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/product-category/designer-bags">Designer Bags</a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/product-category/designer-accessories">Designer Accessories</a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/outright-buying/">Outright Buying</a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/Consignment">Consignment</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code expands the sub menus when a click occurs on `navbar-toggle`
and it change the `aria-expanded` to the correct value based on the open/close state of sub menu

```
function opensubmenus() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $("#top-navbar-collapse li").addClass('open');
        $("#top-navbar-collapse li a").attr('aria-expanded','true');
    }else{
        $("#top-navbar-collapse li").removeClass('open');
        $("#top-navbar-collapse li a").attr('aria-expanded','false');
    }
}

$('#top-menu .navbar-toggle').click(function(){
    setTimeout(opensubmenus, 100);
});

$(window).resize(opensubmenus);
opensubmenus();
```